# Creating a Aspx application with Angular Js

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp-classic, angularjs-scope

Why we must have to use Web APi or Web services in my aspx web application for using Angular Js Insertion,Deletion,Updation.
Is not Possible by creating aspx three tier architectural application (Business Layer and Database Layer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aspx file is a traditional "web forms" application. It was also made back when the common way to update a page's data is to perform a full page reload.

Then came ajax. This made it possible to add in pieces of data from the server without reloading the entire page.

The thing with angular js and any other SPA (single page app) library (mv* library actually) is that you cannot perform a page reload while still retaining your bindings and state. All your html is in one big document. Angular then binds to the document and performs the necessary actions it needs to. You tell angular to get something from the server and stick it into an html element on your page.

Angular needs a way to communicate with with your business logic layer. The only way I know of is to have a web api/service that angular can call via the $http service. You still have a 3 tier application. It's just not the aspx page that will do the processing and rendering.

Comment: Thanks @Praval ,It's a great help but just want to know one more thing is there any other process so that i can create Angular Js application using aspx without any Web Method declaration,Web API, Web Service?

Comment: @Micky I am not 100% sure to be honest. I don't think you can. You could try using an ajax panel but I'm not familiar enough with it to say for sure.